# ¿Cómo crear un PDF con caracteres latinos usando PHP?

Tags: php, pdf

Estoy trabajando con la librería PDFlib en su versión 9 o superior. El caso es que quiero utilizar las tildes, la ñ, el símbolo del €... He leído en el [manual](https://www.pdflib.com/fileadmin/pdflib/pdf/manuals/PDFlib-10.0.0-tutorial.pdf) que $pdf->set_parameter("textformat", "utf8"); está obsoleta, es necesario utilizar pdf_set_option($pdf, "stringformat=utf8"); pero tampoco me sale, en el momento que comenta esa línea ya sí funciona.

¿Alguien ha manejado esta librería con caracteres latinos?

Dejo mi código por si alguien puede ayudarme:

```
$pdf = pdf_new();
pdf_set_option($pdf, "stringformat=utf8");
//$pdf->set_parameter("textformat", "utf8");
PDF_begin_document ($pdf, "BFactura".cortar($texto, "<HoraExpedicionFactura>", "</HoraExpedicionFactura>").".pdf", "compatibility 1.6");
pdf_set_info($pdf, "Autor", "Betivending, S.L.");
pdf_set_info($pdf, "Title", "Factura de respaldo");
pdf_set_info($pdf, "Creator", "Ver Autor");
pdf_set_info($pdf, "Asunto", "Factura respaldo TicketBai");
PDF_begin_page_ext($pdf, 595, 842, "topdown");
pdf_create_bookmark($pdf, "Page 1", "");
$font = PDF_load_font($pdf, "Times-Roman", "host", "");
pdf_setfont($pdf, $font, 18);
pdf_set_value($pdf, "textrendering", 0);
pdf_show_xy($pdf, "Factura simplificada", 50, 50);
```

Comment: Lo primero es verificar que tu editor guarda en utf8.

Comment: Muchas gracias Sal por la respuesta. Investigo sobre ello